# disable main button validation new fields snippet Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working in this post creator, it starts with the main button disabled by default, once the users writes text it gets enabled and is possible to send the form...

**PROBLEM**

Now I want to add an optional Poll...this poll has two textfields to validate if its shown only....

When clicking on `Add Poll` the main form button becomes disabled, and those two textfields become requireds fields. If is decided to delete the poll, those two textfields becomes no required again....and the main button reenable only if there is text on the main text field

So there is two option to reenable the main button:

1) writing text in the main textarea without the poll

2) writing text in the main textarea, add the poll with the two textfieds written.

```js
$("#Add").on("click",function(){ 


$("#pollContainer").show();
$("#SendButton").prop("disabled",true);
});

$("#Delete").on("click",function(){ 

 $("#pollContainer input").val("");
$("#pollContainer").hide();
$("#SendButton").prop("disabled",false);
});

//starting
$("#SendButton").prop("disabled",true);

$("#maintext").on("input",function(){ 

if($("#maintext").val().length==0){
$("#SendButton").prop("disabled",true);
}else{
$("#SendButton").prop("disabled",false);
}


});
```

```css
#pollContainer{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="maintext"></textarea>
   

    <button id="Add">Add New Poll</button> <button id="Delete">delete Poll</button>
    
    <div id="pollContainer">
    <input type=text id="first_entry" /><br/>
    <input type=text id="second_entry" />
    </div>
    
    <hr/>
    
    <input type=submit value="Send" id="SendButton" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to check the value of the poll inputs when they change, and selectively enable and disable the button based on whether or not the poll container is visible

```js
$("#Add").on("click", function() {
    $("#pollContainer").show();
    $("#SendButton").prop("disabled",true);
});

$("#Delete").on("click", function() {
    $("#pollContainer input").val("");
    $("#pollContainer").hide();

    if(should_enable_button()) {
        $("#SendButton").prop("disabled",false);
    }
});

//starting
$("#SendButton").prop("disabled",true);

$("#maintext, #first_entry, #second_entry").on("input", function() {
    if(should_enable_button()) {
        $("#SendButton").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("#SendButton").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});

function should_enable_button() {
    var shouldEnable = false;

    if($("#maintext").val().length > 0)
    {
        if($("#pollContainer").is(":visible")) {
            if($("#first_entry").val().length > 0 && $("#second_entry").val().length > 0) {
                shouldEnable = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            shouldEnable = true;
        }
    }

    return shouldEnable;
}
```

```css
#pollContainer{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="maintext"></textarea>


<button id="Add">Add New Poll</button> <button id="Delete">delete Poll</button>

<div id="pollContainer">
 <input type=text id="first_entry" /><br/>
 <input type=text id="second_entry" />
</div>

<hr/>

<input type=submit value="Send" id="SendButton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $("#Add").on("click", function() {


     $("#pollContainer").show();
     $("#SendButton").prop("disabled", true);
 });

 $("#Delete").on("click", function() {

     $("#pollContainer input").val("");
     $("#pollContainer").hide();
     $("#SendButton").prop("disabled", false);
 });

 //starting
 $("#SendButton").prop("disabled", true);

 $("input, #maintext").keyup(function() {
     if ($("#maintext").val().length == 0) {
         $("#SendButton").prop("disabled", true);
     } else {
         if ($("#pollContainer").is(":visible")) {
             var valStatus = false;
             $("#pollContainer input").each(function() {
                 var input = $(this);
                 if (!input.val() && !input.val().trim().length > 0)
                     valStatus = !valStatus ? true : false;
             });
             $("#SendButton").prop("disabled", valStatus);
         } else {
             $("#SendButton").prop("disabled", false);
         }

     }


 });
```

```css
#pollContainer{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="maintext"></textarea>


<button id="Add">Add New Poll</button> <button id="Delete">delete Poll</button>

<div id="pollContainer">
    <input type=text id="first_entry" /><br/>
    <input type=text id="second_entry" />
</div>

<hr/>

<input type=submit value="Send" id="SendButton" />
```